# Calling a variable variable as a function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just like in the PHP I need a variable variable.

I`m getting a data-type from the html and that variable is actually a function in the js code.

And I get it I need to call it.
Every time its different, so I don`t know which one exactly is.

```
if (e.which == 114 || e.which == 116) {
    var action = $('.active').data("action");    
    action();
}

function testing() {
    alert('yes');
}
```

Here the function name is testing.And the variable action is holding it.
How I`m suppose to call it ?!
I remember that there was a easy syntax for that,but I cant find it.
Thanks

Comment: If `testing` is in the global scope you can do `window[action]()`, **but** I really suggest you rethink your logic. "variable variables" don't exist in JS and they're are bad practice in PHP anyway.

Comment: Its not working..
The main idea is to escape this
if(action == 'player_select'){
                player_select();
}
Where the functions will be more than 10-15

Comment: Quote : I see that you've already asked a few questions but haven't accepted any answers. Perhaps you should take a look at [this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to learn how accepting an answer works on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/). Accepting an answer lets other users know that you've solved your issue and it also helps future visitors having similar problems to identify the most helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the object which holds the function. For the global scope use : `window[action]()`. Otherwise, replace `window` with the name of your object : `myObject[action]()`. However, this solution is not suitable for functions declared inside a private scope :

```
function f(fnName) {
    function a() { alert('a') };
    function b() { alert('b') };
    fnName(); // error
}
```

In this case, you could use eval like this (⚠ keep control over inputs ⚠) :

```
function f(fnName) {
    function a() { alert('a') };
    function b() { alert('b') };
    eval(fnName)();
}
```

Otherwise you could wrap them inside an object like so :

```
function f(fnName) {
    var wrapper = {};
    wrapper.a = function () { alert('a') };
    wrapper.b = function () { alert('b') };
    wrapper[fnName]();
}

f('a'); // alerts "a"
f('b'); // alerts "b"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the value and use eval().

```
<div id="something" data-action="alert('test')">SOME DIV</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var $myObject = $("#something");
    var action = $myObject.data('action');
    $myObject.click(function() {
        eval(action);
    });    
});
```

[Try it yourself on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vtj62/)

[However, eval is evil](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/01/53329.aspx)

Comment: You should complete with : http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/06/25/eval-isnt-evil-just-misunderstood/ :)